# Graph matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on my first big data project for my university. My dataset is this one: https://www.kaggle.com/carolzhangdc/imdb-5000-movie-dataset

In this part I'd like to:

- Take only the best 20 variables of that particular column (IMDB Score
  and Gross)
- Plot everything to see the graph.

With this code I can see the graph as shown [image: graph]

```
Top20 = newmovieDef[['IMDB Score', 'Gross']].sort_values('IMDB Score', ascending=False).nlargest(20, 'IMDB Score')
newmovieDef[['IMDB Score', 'Gross']].sort_values('IMDB Score', ascending=False).nlargest(20, 'IMDB Score')
#visualizing top 20 in plot
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
x = Top20["IMDB Score"]
y = Top20["Gross"]
plt.bar(x, y, color="purple")
plt.show()
```

But if then I write this:

```
#GROSS-DURATION ---PROBLEMA GRAFICO
Top20 = newmovieDef[['Gross', 'Duration']].sort_values('Gross', ascending=False).nlargest(20, 'Gross')
newmovieDef[['Gross', 'Duration']].sort_values('Gross', ascending=False).nlargest(20, 'Gross')
#visualizing top 20 in plot
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
x = Top20["Gross"]
y = Top20["Duration"]
plt.bar(x, y, color="green")
plt.show()
```

it gives me a blank graph as in [image: empty graph]

Comment: Can you print x and y before plotting?

Answer (score 0):

`Gross` and `Duration` are continuous variables so a **bar** chart with `Gross` on the xaxis and `Duration` on the yaxis is not the right choice for a visualization. To see the relationship between two continuous variables (in this case `Gross` and `Duration`), generally, a **scatter (X-Y)** plot is used.

From [this source](https://nces.ed.gov/nceskids/help/user_guide/graph/whentouse.asp), "Bar graphs are used to compare things between different groups or to track changes over time." The key word here is *groups* which means discrete variables (usually represented as strings in Python).

From the same source, "X-Y plots are used to determine relationships between the two different things. The x-axis is used to measure one event (or variable) and the y-axis is used to measure the other."

You can modify your code to show a scatter (X-Y) plot as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
x = Top20["Gross"]
y = Top20["Duration"]
# Scatter plot
plt.plot(x, y, color="green")
plt.show()
```

If you really want a bar plot, then I would suggest [binning your continuous data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html). This breaks a continuous variable into discrete groups which can then be shown on a bar graph although this is still not the best choice for the visualization.

[This book](https://serialmentor.com/dataviz/) is an exceptional (free) resource for data visualization. It's written with the R programming language, but the general principles still apply.